# Как подключить javadoc в Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, openstreetmap

Использую в своём приложении OSMBonusPack.
Есть javadoc, как подключить не знаю.
В интернете нашёл, что подключение должно быть аналогично IntelliJ IDEA,
но в Project structure не нашел нужных настроек.
Насколько я понимаю, библиотека должна быть в разделе modules, 
но там только app, самой библиотеки(OSMBonusPack) там нет.

Comment: библиотека подключена как JAR-файл? Или как модуль?

Comment: Добавил *.jar в папку libs, затем "Add as library"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tools - sdk manager - source for android sdk, если студия попросит путь - указать из папки sdk нужного api

Comment: меня интересует документация не для API Android, 
а для подключаемой библиотеки.
https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/source/browse/#svn%2FBonusPackDownloads

Comment: скачай исходники библиотеки, открой класс либы, студия попросит путь к исходникам, укажи путь к сорцам